# Creating lists that preserve order

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to convert an array of arrays into a list. Sounds strange? 
The array A looks like this:

```
 array([array(['Afr_004'], 
  dtype='<U7'),
   array(['Afr_005'], 
  dtype='<U7'),
   array(['Afr_012'], 
  dtype='<U7'), ...,
   array(['SAm_029'], 
  dtype='<U7'),
   array(['SAm_030'], 
  dtype='<U7'),
   array(['SAm_031'], 
  dtype='<U7')], dtype=object)
```

and was obtained by loading data from a .mat file via `scipy.io.load()`. I have no idea why it chose such an ugly an inconvenient structure for what should be a list of strings. I tried to convert A to such a list in a variety of ways:
1) `L = np.concatenate(A).ravel()`
or 2) `L = [x[0] for x in A]`

Both work great, but sort the underlying elements alphabetically:

```
['Afr_004', 'Afr_005', 'Afr_012', 'Ant_001', 'Ant_002']
```

You can see that the first 3 elements of L (above) are identical to A, but the next 3 are not. Now, it turns out that sorting is what I *eventually* want to do with this list, but not before capturing the indices of the sorted list (I need those indices to re-order another array based on the list L).

So, 2 questions:

1. is there a way to obtain an unsorted L from A?
2. do I even need to so that, or is there a more Pythonic way to index my array based on L (instead of the default order, which follows A)?

Thanks in advance for forgiving my lack of knowledge of Python data structures.

Comment: Your data must have been sorted before being stored.

Comment: It may not be obvious from what I posted, but i am positive that A is not sorted, and neither are the other arrays in that mat file.

Comment: The only A you are showing is sorted.  In addition, list comprehensions, and lists in general do *not* sort.

Comment: it is not sorted: the elements 'Ant_001', 'Ant_002', which appear in 4th and 5th position in L, are further down the list in A.

Answer (score 1):

In an Octave session I made `c` and saved it

```
c = {'Afr_004','Afr_005','Afr_012','SAm_031','SAm_029','Ant_001','Ant_002','SAm_030'}
```

In Ipython

```
In [55]: arr=data['c']
In [56]: arr
Out[56]: 
array([[array(['Afr_004'], 
      dtype='<U7'),
        array(['Afr_005'], 
      dtype='<U7'),
        array(['Afr_012'], 
      dtype='<U7'),
        array(['SAm_031'], 
      dtype='<U7'),
        array(['SAm_029'], 
      dtype='<U7'),
        array(['Ant_001'], 
      dtype='<U7'),
        array(['Ant_002'], 
      dtype='<U7'),
        array(['SAm_030'], 
      dtype='<U7')]], dtype=object)
```

That looks a lot like yours, except it is 2d; `arr[0]` takes care of the extra dimension.  It's an object array because a MATLAB cell can contain 'anything', like Python lists.  The order is the same when created.

```
In [59]: L = np.concatenate(arr[0]).ravel()
In [60]: L
Out[60]: 
array(['Afr_004', 'Afr_005', 'Afr_012', 'SAm_031', 'SAm_029', 'Ant_001', 'Ant_002', 'SAm_030'], 
      dtype='<U7')

In [61]: L1 = [x[0] for x in arr[0]]
In [62]: L1
Out[62]: 
['Afr_004',
 'Afr_005',
 'Afr_012',
 'SAm_031',
 'SAm_029',
 'Ant_001',
 'Ant_002',
 'SAm_030']
```

Same order with both of your methods.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an old-fashioned loop to construct the list I wanted

```
N = len(A)
L = ["?" for x in range(N)] # initialize list
for r in range(N): 
    L[r] = A[0][r][0]
```

The list is sorted, even though A is not, at least looking at the array in the Spyder variable explorer, or the IPython prompt. I suspect the problem is with the shape of this array. I ended up pursuing another route involving the same list of strings exported to Excel, and the openpyxl package. No problems there.

Comment: Your code can simplify to `N = len(A); L = [A[0][i][0] for i in range(N)]`.